# why the POST Array element is not displaying?

Tags: php

I have a form with method post and i have html selection box which is displaying my options. my option value is 'id_service'. When click on the button, it posts the array to auth_insert.php . Here is my form below.

```
$rvar_service="SELECT id_s,nom_s FROM tablename WHERE company LIKE '%tous%' OR societe LIKE '%me%'";
$var_service = $conn->query($rvar_service);

<form action='filePost.php' method='POST' style='background-color:#FF6600;'>
    <?php if($var_service->num_rows>0){ ?>
     <fieldset>
     <legend><h3>Services déjà Autorisés</h3></legend>
     <select name='nservice[]' size='15'>
     <?php while($var_service_row = $var_service->fetch_assoc()) { 
                echo "<option value=".$var_service_row['id_s'].">".$var_service_row['nom_s']."</option>" ?>     
    <?php } } ?>
    </select>

    <div style='text-align:right;'><input type='submit' value='Autoriser'></div>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
```

My post file is called auth_insert.php is below. In this file i have posted the variable which print my array. that array variable doesn't print it's elements. i don't where is the problem exist.

```
session_start();
$code_e=$_SESSION['ecoutant'];  
$id_s = $_POST['nservice']; 

print'<pre>';
print $code_e.'<br/>';
print $id_s;
print'<pre>';
```

Comment: Is `session_start();` inside all files that are using sessions? Plus, this `$code_ecoutant=$_SESSION['ecoutant'];` doesn't do much. You're just assigning a variable to a session name.

Comment: It looks like your form is going to `auth_add.php` instead, and your select is called `nservice`, not `in_service`. But try doing `print_r($id_service1);` instead.

Comment: @putvande There is no "in_service" in OP's code. The select is named `<select name='nservice[]' size='15'>`

Comment: @Techappri Reload my first comment, I made an edit to it.

Comment: That is what I said @Fred-ii-.

Comment: @putvande I'm confused. You wrote *"and your select is called `nservice`, not `in_service`"* which is why am wondering where you got the `in_service` from. I don't see it in OP's question.

Comment: @Fred-ii: there is nothing any problem with session variable. it's working well. But the $_POST['nservice'] is not working

Comment: @putvande:  Ok, With print_r it's showing my array element. Thank you.